# Content type check for uploading APK file in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to check if user is actually uploading APK file in java.

By checking only the **extension** of file user can rename any file(Eg:TXT file) to **apk** and upload.

I tried to check the `contentType` of the particular file as shown below:

```
if(apkFile.getContentType().equals("application/vnd.android.package-archive"))
```

But here the problem is when upload from some browser the `content type` comes as `application/vnd.android.package-archive` but for some others its `application/octet-stream`.

What is the proper way to check this?

Comment: IMHO,Reading files first **4-byte** may be determine the file type.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I didn't get , could you pelase describe a bit.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I will check and update. behind some other issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Apache tika parser`** can detect your file type if you changed the file type extension by renaming.Though parse method a bit expensive. After parsing the file, file metadata are stored in `MetaData` object. However you can follow the code

```
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String contentType = null;

        try {
            //suppose f.apk file you renamed it f.txt
            file = new File("path\\to\\your\\file\\f.txt");
            is = new FileInputStream(file);

            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

            try {
                // This step takes some time.
                parser.parse(is, handler, metadata);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }

            contentType = metadata.get("Content-Type");
            System.out.println("Content Type = " + contentType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Required maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apk is formated in `zip`,so you could check whether it's a zip file to decrease  the probability that it' not an apk file ,in addtion to checking the file extension.After all ,not all of the marplots change file extensions only from zip to apk